# Maximum recursion depth exceeded in databricks when converting pandas dataframe to spark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm currently writing some code in databricks, with the default language in my notebook being python.  I have a function that takes a pandas dataframe as input, does some calculations, and then outputs the dataframe with a new column that contains the output from the function.  The function works as expected, and it outputs a pandas dataframe.  However, when I then try and convert the outputted pandas dataframe to a spark dataframe, using `result = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)` I get the following error:

maximum recursion depth exceeded in **instancecheck**

I can convert the pandas dataframe to a spark dataframe prior to the function call, and I know that the function work s as expected as I can see the output, however, every time I try and convert back to a spark dataframe, I get the error.

Comment: what is the code of your function? can you provide it with an example?

Comment: I can't provide the function code as it'll breach company data protection - it's quite a long function.  The function itself, while producing output, isn't producing what I'd expect so I'm currently trying to sort that out.  Nevertheless, I would still expect to be able to convert a pandas dataframe into spark dataframe using spark.createDataFrame() function if I'm able to view the pandas dataframe.

Comment: can you provide the sample output pandas dataframe?

Comment: *"... maximum recursion depth exceeded"* means there is a recursion (loops) within the function. check/update that piece.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge the error didn't occur for you because the version of PySpark or Pandas you are using.
The issue is with **maximum recursion depth**

Thank you @**[JAMES GALLAGHER](https://careerkarma.com/blog/author/jamesgallagher/)**Please refer this [BLOG](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-in-comparison/) as an example i am using a recursive function that calculates the Fibonacci Sequence:
If you write a recursive function that executes over a certain number of iterations,
you will face  the **“maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison”** Python error.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        return(fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2))
```

**calling the function**

```
print(fibonacci(5000))
```

[image]

use an iterative approach instead of a recursive approach
In this iterative version of the function, we specifing  the dtype parameter as np.int64 for all series objects to make sure that they can handle larger integer values. This can avoid the overflow in long.
[image]
[image]
If you write a recursive function that executes more than a particular number of iterations **(usually 997)**,
you will  see an error when you get to the next iteration.

This is because Python limits the depth of a recursion algorithm.

This command will help you view in your code.

```
import sys
print(sys.getrecursionlimit()
```

)
[image]

You can override the default recursion limit Python sets using the setrecursionlimit() method:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

[image]

This code sets the maximum recursion depth to 5,000. You should also  be careful when you use this method because it may cause a overflow depending on the resources available to the Python interpreter also.